actionButton does not work in page_navbar
I abstract demo from code:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    checkboxInput("sltAccessible", "Accessible", value = FALSE),
    actionButton("btnChat", 'chat')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sltedAccessible <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  observe({
    sltedAccessible(input$sltAccessible)
  })

  observeEvent(input$btnChat, {
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "sltAccessible", value = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The button does not work under this code.
I tried to find the reason and when I changed page_navbar() to something else like fluidpage() or page_sidebar(), it works!
But why I can't use page_navbar(), if I change this part, a lot of work need to be done in my project. Can anyone find a way to use page_navbar() instead without change the basic structure?

You must put your button and checkbox inside a nav_item() element, inside the page_navbar():
ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "App with navbar",
  nav_item(
    checkboxInput("sltAccessible", "Accessible", value = FALSE),
    actionButton("btnChat", 'chat')
    )
)


it works! thank you julien

You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer ;)
